# Vaadin 14.9.7 - Slow Compile for Production

Tags: performance, build, package, production, vaadin14

I'm currently using Vaadin with Spring Boot and I've recently upgraded platform version from 14.8.18 to 14.9.7. Before the upgrade my artifact for production was built in approximately 90 seconds, while after the upgrade the same package is produced in 480 - 540 seconds. I've noticed that there is a repeatedly check for the pro license of all the pro components during the build, even if I have the license installed on my development workstation and really I don't use many of them in my source code. Anyway by checking the logs, it seems the build is stuck for many seconds in doing "Reading file /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/product_uuid" as per the log below.

Is there a way to speed up the process? Why the build process slowed down by mean of the platform upgrade?

Many thanks,
Giuseppe.

[DEBUG] Checking if license for Product [name=vaadin-grid-pro, version=2.3.1] has recently been checked
[DEBUG] Last check for Product [name=vaadin-grid-pro, version=2.3.1] was on 2023-03-23T07:37:08.193Z
[DEBUG] Skipping check as product license was recently validated.
[DEBUG] Checking license for Product [name=vaadin-rich-text-editor, version=1.3.2]
[DEBUG] Reading file /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/product_uuid

Comment: You can try upgrading the license checker to a newer version to see if it resolves the problem:

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>license-checker</artifactId>
                <version>1.12.3</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>

Comment: Just tried, it doesn't solve, still slow

Comment: I think you should create an issue in https://github.com/vaadin/platform/issues/new/choose with the full log of the build

Comment: thanks for your support and suggestion, I've opened https://github.com/vaadin/platform/issues/3983